# SO C++ forbids comparison between pointer and integer [-fpermissive]

Tags: c++, строки, сравнение

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
  cout << "Enter your number: ";
  int name = 0;
  cin >> name;
  while ( name == "10" ) {
    name++;
    break;
  }
  if ( name == "10" ) /* Error */ {
    cout << "Yes" << endl;
  }
  // Framed message
  const string greeting = "This your number: " + name;
  const string spaces(greeting.size(), '$');
  const string first = "$" + spaces + "$";
  const string second(first.size(), '$');
  cout << endl;
  cout << second << endl;
  cout << first << endl;
  cout << "$" << greeting << "$";
  cout << second << endl;
  cout << first << endl;
  return 0;
}
```

Я уже 2 дня пытаюсь понять проблему но не получается, вот моя проблема:

```
ISO C++ forbids comparison between pointer and integer [-fpermissive]
```

Жду вашего ответа и буду очень рад если поможете, оценю!

Answer (score 1):

```
if ( name == "10" )
```

Вы сравниваете `int` слева и `const char *` справа, что не нравится компилятору, и он такое запрещает. Если вам хочется сравнить со значением 10, то так и напишите `name == 10` без использования строкового литерала.

Comment: Спасибо вам, без вас я сидел как баран на новых воротах)

Answer (score 1):

Сравнение

```
name == "10"
```

сравнивает (пытается!) целое число в переменной `name` типа `int` и — внимание! — указатель на строку `"10"`. Вряд ли это то, что вы хотели?

Сравнивайте просто числа:

```
name == 10
```